# Jquery: preventing mass hover events until mouse is in element for 0.5 sec

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have a list of menu items which use the hover event to show a dynamic area. The problem is that as the user moves over the individual menu items, each menu item triggers the toggle() event, resulting in a mass of show/hide events being fired before you get to the actual menu element you want.

```
    jQuery(".categoryPopupLink").hover(
            function () {
                    var str = jQuery(this).attr('id');
                    var id  = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);

                    jQuery (".categoryPopup:visible").toggle (750);

                    jQuery ("#categoryPopup_" + id).toggle (750);
                    return false;
            }
    );
```

How can I modify this code so that the toggle() events are only fired if the mouse remains over the menu element for a specific duration of time (for example, 0.5 sec).

Comment: You could use a plugin like [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

Comment: Can you show us the `mouseover` or `mouseenter` event handler, or is that is above, but with the wrong event?

Comment: Sorry, pasted older version of the code, I now corrected it.

Comment: OK, got a version with hoverIntent to work. Thanks for pointing me towards that highly useful plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var timeoutID = 0;

jQuery(".categoryPopupLink")
    .on("mouseenter", function () {
        var str = this.id;
        var id  = str.substring(str.indexOf("_") + 1);
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery(".categoryPopup:visible").hide();
            jQuery("#categoryPopup_" + id).show();
        }, 500);
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
        jQuery(".categoryPopup:visible").hide();
    });
```

It should leave a 500ms pause before showing the element.

Comment: I tried it. That does implement a timeout, but still all the mouseover evnets fire. Just want the last one (in which the user pauses the mouse) to fire. Can this be implemented using your technique?

Comment: You're going to have to post some html in your question.  If there's something in your script that referencing the DOM incorrectly then I can't help without seeing it :)